# Not getting null values when no data available

Tags: sql-server-2008

In my stored procedure, I declared @account_id, which sets as per the serial number.
if there are no matching records for the SERIAL_NUMBER, @account_id is not getting NULL value. WHERE condition is mentioned in section B. 
So, when I pass invalid serial number, still records are coming which shouldn't. Please guide me to solve this issue.

```
Section A:
DECLARE @Account_ID INT         
SELECT @Account_ID = ACCOUNT_ID FROM T_ACCOUNT WITH (NOLOCK) WHERE SERIAL_NUMBER = @Serial_Number            

Section B:
WHERE             
  (@Account_ID IS NULL OR Acct.ACCOUNT_ID = @Account_ID)
```

Comment: `@Account_ID` **will** be `NULL` if there are no matching rows in section `A`. No assignment is made to the variable and it will have its previous value of `NULL`. But your `WHERE` says to bring back all rows in section B if that is the case.

Comment: How is the WHERE in Section B related to Section A? In Section A there already is a WHERE clause!?

Comment: Hi Martin, how to get no records if invalid serial number is given. Can you suggest

Comment: Remove the `@Account_ID IS NULL OR` from your second `WHERE`. Or if you need to distinguish between it being `NULL` as nothing assigned and `NULL` passed in explicitly as a parameter value then you can check `@@ROWCOUNT` immediately after the assignment.

Comment: I'm confused why you have two practically identical questions, asked only 2 hours apart. Other one [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17062646/sql-server-where-clause-for-optional-fields)

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
Section A:
DECLARE @Account_ID INT         
SELECT @Account_ID = ACCOUNT_ID FROM T_ACCOUNT WITH (NOLOCK) WHERE SERIAL_NUMBER = @Serial_Number            

Section B:
WHERE             
  Acct.ACCOUNT_ID = @Account_ID
```

In your query you are using OR condition where your query return all the records even if the variable @AccountId is NULL.