# SQL server: where clause for optional fields

Tags: sql-server-2008

Track Id is optional field in my application.
Case 1: If I pass valid track id, it should return the respective rows. 
Case 2: If invalid track id is passed, no rows should be returned.
Case 3: If no track id passed, all rows should be returned

```
DECLARE @transaction_ID INT     
SELECT @transaction_ID = Transaction_ID FROM myTable WHERE TRACK_ID= @Track_Id
```

My where condition is:

```
WHERE (@transaction_ID IS NULL OR myTable.Transaction_ID = @transaction_ID)            
  AND (amount<>0)
```

with the above condition 1 and 3 cases are working fine. but 2nd case got failed. When I passed invalid track id, all rows are getting returned. Please correct the query to handle the case 2. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just continue to query `@Track_ID` as well:

```
WHERE (
       (@transaction_ID IS NULL AND @Track_Id IS NULL) OR
       myTable.Transaction_ID = @transaction_ID)            
AND (amount<>0)
```

(The only situation where you want a `NULL` `@Transaction_ID` to make this `WHERE` clause succeed is case 3. In Case 2, a non-null `@Track_Id` was passed but `@Transaction_ID` will be `NULL` because no rows were returned, so that's the situation we're trying to deal with)

Comment: Thank you Damien_The_Unbeliever.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this

Where 1=(Case when  @TrackId = 1 Or TRACK_ID= @Track_Id  then 1 else 0 end )

When you want all the data then pass 1 ,

When want data as per TrackID pass @trackID value and 
when you dont wnat the condition to be applied pass null